# Ansible - Find and Replace

Tags: ansible

Use case

1. List all files in a directory with the format - `a1.{{ env }}.js`, `a2.{{ env }}.js`
2. Find corresponding files in the destination directory with the format - `a1.js`, `a2.js`
3. Copy `a1.{{ env }}.js` in the directory where `a1.js` exists, Copy `a2.{{ env }}.js` in the directory where `a2.js` exists

Sample code: This code does a direct find and replace

```yaml
- name: Find files in archive
  find:
    paths: "archive/"
    file_type: file
    recurse: yes
  register: tmp_file_path

- name: Find files in code matching names in archive
  find:
    paths: "code/"
    file_type: file
    recurse: yes
    patterns: "{{ tmp_file_path.files | map(attribute='path') | map('basename') | list }}"
  register: code_file_path

- set_fact:
    code_files: "{{ code_files|default([]) +
                    [{'path': item, 'name': item|basename}] }}"
  loop: "{{ code_file_path.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"

- name: Copy files from archive to code directory
  command: cp "{{ item.0 }}" "{{ item.1.path }}"
  when:
    - item.0|basename == item.1.path|basename
  with_together:
    - "{{ tmp_file_path.files|map(attribute='path')|list|sort }}"
    - "{{ code_files|sort(attribute='name') }}"
```

Below listed is the directory structure

```
├── archive
│   ├── a1.test.js
│   ├── a2.test.js
│   ├── a3.test.js
│   └── a4.test.js
└── code
    ├── a1.js
    ├── dir1
    │   └── a2.js
    └── dir2
        ├── a4.js
        └── dir3
            └── a3.js
```

- Copy `archive/a1.test.js` to `code/`
- Copy `archive/a2.test.js` to `code/dir1/`
- Copy `archive/a3.test.js` to `code/dir1/dir2/dir3/`
- Copy `archive/a4.test.js` to `code/dir1/dir2/`

Is there a solution to do a direct copy as per the above use case?

Comment: The expectation is it should copy and replace all the files in case of multiple files as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some explanation on the approach:

1. The entire idea of it is based on the creation of a dictionary instructing the playbook on which file should be added where.
   The dictionary, for your use case would look like this:

   ```
   {
       "a1.js": {
           "archive": "archive/a1.test.js",
           "paths": [
               "code"
           ]
       },
       "a2.js": {
           "archive": "archive/a2.test.js",
           "paths": [
               "code/dir1"
           ]
       },
       "a3.js": {
           "archive": "archive/a3.test.js",
           "paths": [
               "code/dir1/dir2/dir3"
           ]
       },
       "a4.js": {
           "archive": "archive/a4.test.js",
           "paths": [
               "code/dir1/dir2"
           ]
       }
   }
   ```

   Where the keys are the files we are searching for under the `code` folder, the key `archive` represent the file we aim to copy from the `archive` folder and `paths` is an array where the said file should find its destination(s).
2. Most of the logic is done by the Ansible filter [`regex_replace`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters), that extract the name of the file to find in the `code` folder via a quite simple expression: [`(.*)\..*\.js$`](https://regex101.com/r/NxX5Xi/1)

   ```yaml
   item.path | basename | regex_replace('(.*)\\..*\\.js$', '\\1.js')
   ```
3. Another filter used here that might be interesting to explore is the [`combine`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) filter, with the parameter `recursive=true`, that allows to create the `paths` where the files should find their destination(s).
4. There is also a Python operation used here: [`dict.keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=keys#dict.keys), in order to create the comma separated list of files to search in the `code` folder out of the keys of the dictionary above.
5. It is also making use of `loop` with the [`subelement`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-subelements) filter, to traverse both the dictionary and its sub array `paths` at the same time.
6. And to be complete, here are the other, more commonly used filters used in this playbook:

   - [`default`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#default): to specify a default value when a variable is not defined
   - [`basename`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8): to get only the name of a file out of its full path
   - [`dirname`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8): to get only the directory from a full path to a file
   - [`join`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#join): to concatenate the elements of an array, here, based on a separator
7. Yes, it might be over-engineered compared to your use case, the playbook here-under is able to cope with the fact that `a1.js` could be in two different folders and will be able to copy `a1.test.js` in both those folders.

So, here is a solution:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - find:
        paths: archive
        file_type: file
        recurse: yes
      register: archives

    - set_fact:
        searches: "{{ searches | default({}) | combine({ key: value }) }}"
      vars: 
        key: "{{ item.path | basename | regex_replace('(.*)\\..*\\.js$', '\\1.js') }}"
        value: "{{ { 'archive': item.path, 'paths': [] } }}"   
      loop: "{{ archives.files }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.path }}"

    - find:
        path: code
        file_type: file
        recurse: yes
        pattern: "{{ searches.keys() | join(',') }}"
      register: paths

    - set_fact: 
        searches: "{{ searches | combine({key: value}, recursive=true) }}"
      vars:
        key: "{{ item.path | basename }}"
        value: "{{ { 'paths': [item.path | dirname] + searches[item.path | basename].paths } }}"
      loop: "{{ paths.files }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.path }}"

    - copy:
        src: "{{ item.0.archive }}"
        dest: "{{ item.1 ~ '/' ~ item.0.archive | basename }}"
      loop: "{{ searches | subelements('paths') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.archive }}"
```

Situation before:

```
tree archive code
archive
├── a1.test.js
├── a2.test.js
├── a3.test.js
└── a4.test.js
code
├── a1.js
└── dir1
    ├── a2.js
    └── dir2
        ├── a4.js
        └── dir3
            └── a3.js

3 directories, 8 files
```

Recap of the playbook:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************

TASK [find] *******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ***************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=archive/a3.test.js)
ok: [localhost] => (item=archive/a2.test.js)
ok: [localhost] => (item=archive/a1.test.js)
ok: [localhost] => (item=archive/a4.test.js)

TASK [find] *******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ***************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=code/a1.js)
ok: [localhost] => (item=code/dir1/a2.js)
ok: [localhost] => (item=code/dir1/dir2/a4.js)
ok: [localhost] => (item=code/dir1/dir2/dir3/a3.js)

TASK [copy] *******************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=archive/a3.test.js)
changed: [localhost] => (item=archive/a2.test.js)
changed: [localhost] => (item=archive/a1.test.js)
changed: [localhost] => (item=archive/a4.test.js)

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Situation after:

```
tree code
code
├── a1.js
├── a1.test.js
└── dir1
    ├── a2.js
    ├── a2.test.js
    └── dir2
        ├── a4.js
        ├── a4.test.js
        └── dir3
            ├── a3.js
            └── a3.test.js

3 directories, 8 files
```

Comment: Is there a way I can add filters for multiple file types apart from js. Here I need to copy files with .json and .pem as well. Can you update with the syntax for the same also?